# Orthogonal problem

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

Show that $$xy=a, a≠0$$ is orthogonal to every curve $$x^2-y^2=b, b≠0$$

So I know, that the derivative at every intersecting curve is perpendicular.
I don't know how to continue this problem because of the a and b.

Comment: Just differentiate both equations with respect to $x$ using implicit differentiation.  The $a$ and $b$ will differentiate to $0$.

Comment: wait so is a and b constants? What about a≠0 and b≠0

Comment: What do you mean? $a$ can be negative or positive. BUT $a$ is a constant, isn't it? like $a=-100, a=-1,a=1, a=100$

Comment: I understand now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what techniques you're expected to use, but a very basic way of showing it is to differentiate the two equations and solve for $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ in both. This gives you the equations of the tangent lines at all points. Orthogonal lines have slopes that are the negative reciprocal of each other and that's precisely what we get.

Differentiating gives:

$y + x \dfrac{dy}{dx} = 0$

and

$2x - 2y \dfrac{dy}{dx} = 0$

Solving as aforementioned shows that the tangent lines are perpendicular.

Comment: I was able to get it after Stephen's told me, but thanks for explain orthogonal clearly to me

Answer (score 2):

If $xy=a,~~a\neq0$ then $y'=\frac{-a}{x^2}=\frac{-y}{x}$ so the solutions of the differential equation $y'=\frac{x}{y}$ describe the orthogonal curves. $$y'=\frac{x}{y}\to y\frac{dy}{dx}=x\Longrightarrow \frac{y^2}{2}=\frac{x^2}{2}+C$$ where $C$ is a constant.

Comment: This deserves an upvote! +1 ;-)

Comment: Nice to see you awakened. Have a good day. I am going to go to a party. :-)

Comment: Ahhh! Enjoy yourself!! (Don't forget to take one of your MSE hats along!)

Answer (score 1):

From the first equation, you'll get $y+xy^\prime=0.$

From the second equation, you'll get $2x-2yy^\prime=0.$ Then?